# Retrieve TextBox By Name

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox

In my project i know the names of `TextBoxes` which are dynamically generated is there any solution to retrieve this `TextBox` text from other methods.In other sense i want to get `TextBox`  by name and want to use in other part of code.
I have `TextBox` allocated like this...

```
private void Met(string rowNo)
{
    TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
    t2.Name = "itemAmt" + rowNo;
    PurchaseItemEntryDyPanel.Controls.Add(t2);

}
```

Is there any way other than using name? Any Solution?

Comment: Which framework? wpf? winform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personaly use `name`  when I want to read posted data from a form.

And I would use `Id` when controls are supposed to be unique. So the code is a little different:

```
var t2 = new TextBox();
t2.ID = "itemAmt" + rowNo;
//since you mention in the comments, add it to the panel
yourPanel.Controls.Add(t2);
```

Then to get the textBox value

```
var controlId = "itemAmt" + rowNo;
var t2 = ((TextBox)(yourPanel.FindControl(controlId)));
if(t2 != null)
{
  //do someting
  //t2.Text = "something";
  //t2.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

If you are not willing to make that change, go over the solution posted earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your `TextBox` from [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection of Form by it's name like this:

```
var myTextBox = this.Controls[textBoxName];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show too much of your code, but I assume you're adding it to the collection of controls on your form. Otherwise, the `TextBox` you create in `Met` goes out of scope when your method ends, just like any other local variable.

```
private void Met(string rowNo)
{
    TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
    t2.Name = "itemAmt" + rowNo;

    this.Controls.Add(t2);  // need to add the TextBox to your form's controls
}
```

Then you can use Selman22's solution or, if the control might be added to a `GroupBox` or `Panel`, you'll want to search all child controls too:

```
var myControl = this.Controls.Find("itemAmt4", true);

if (myControl != null)
    myControl.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: @AskThakare, in the code snippet in your comment, you never added the control to the panel or the current container (this), so it is not in the controls collection.  Creating a new widget does not automatically add it to the controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Class:

```
foreach (Control tempCtrl in this.Controls)
{
    // Determine he control is textBox1, 

    if (tempCtrl.Name == "itemAmt" + rowNo)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(tempCtrl);
    }
}
```